# How to insert into a table field with a dynamic string?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Im working in AX 2012.
I try to make code where i count all sales for each month and insert them into fields in a table.
These fields are called Sales1, Sales2, Sales3 etc... representing the months in a year.

is there a way i can select these fields and insert into them in a while select like this example below?

```
while select myTable where myTable.date >= startDate && myTable.date <= endDate
{
     MyTable.("Sales" +MthOfYear(MyTable.Date)) += MyTable.SalesQty;
}

myTable.insert();
```

it's a stupid example, but it should show what i want to achieve... any ideas?

Regards
Kent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your main question is how to access a field by having its name in a string variable?
If that's the case then please see the following two links:

[How to convert field name to its ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa887427.aspx)

[How to access a table field by ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa849396.aspx)

In short: First of all you have to convert your field name to the corresponding field ID by using `fieldName2Id`. After that, you can access this field by using the syntax `myTable.(fieldId)`.

To put it all together for your case:

```
myTable.(fieldName2Id(myTable.TableId, strfmt("%1%2", "Sales", mthofyr(myTable.Date)))) += myTable.SalesQty
```

If you have any problems or questions don't hesitate to ask via a comment.

Comment: That gives me a pleasure. Please accept it as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

While the [fieldName2Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa887427.aspx) may save your day, it is an AX anti-pattern to have fields named `Sales1`, `Sales2` ... `Sales17`. Why? Because AX supports arrays in tables (albeit only of a fixed size).

To use that, define a new extended data type `SalesAmountMonth` exending `SalesAmount` (or whatever).
Label the it "January". Then in the node "Array Elements" add an new array element for "February", "Marts" up till "December". See [How to Define an Extended Data Type as an Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa675074.aspx).

Then add the extended data type to your table.

Your field access is then quite simple:

```
myTable.Sales[mthofyr(myTable.Date)] += myTable.SalesQty;
```

I prefer using the [intvNo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa886774.aspx) function for date indexing like this, as it has more flexibility:

```
myTable.Sales[intvNo(myTable.date, startDate, IntvScale::YearMonth) + 1] += myTable.SalesQty;
```

By changing the [IntvScale](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/intvscale.aspx) enumeration you can group by month, week, quarter or whatever it supports.